# Repeated groups in SubReport

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I'm getting a weird behavior with groups in a sales invoice format:

This company has products with two currencies, local and foreign, in the documents (for legal reasons) the foreign prices must be printed along with its equivalent in the local currency, for a clear presentation I want to split the items in the sales invoice into two or more groups (assuming it could be more than two currencies in the future).

I did set items groups according to the currency name, which it works... but repeating the groups many times instead of just two. Seems to me like ReportBuilder is grouping items according to its relative, this is: in a list of 15 items if only the first 5 and the last 5 have foreign currency will be display in two separated groups, with local currency items in the middle (so theoretically speaking if there will be an invoice with foreign currency items in the odd rows and local currency items in the pair rows it will be display in ten groups instead of two).

I tried changing the field group to the ID currency instead of the name currency with the same result.

I'm using Digital Metaphors **ReportBuilder Enterprise Edition v11.06** (inside a management software package with no access to its source code).

Answer (score 0):

ReportBuilder traverses records as provided. If it encounters a value in the data field of the group different than that from the previous record, it starts a new group.

Ensure that your data model is sorted on the data field of the group. Currency name, or currency id in your case.

You do that by specifying an ORDER BY clause in the data model of the data pipeline of the subreport. See the Data tab of the designer:

[image: Screenshot of ReportBuilder Designer's main tabs]

Comment: I was thinking about that since I posted the message, but I don't have an idea how to sort the sales detail records, can I do that in a closed source software using ReportBuilder...?

Comment: I think I found the answer: "Note: Because groups are based on a change in field value, the field on which a group is based should always be used to order the records. ReportBuilder does not sort records; therefore, you must order the records using an Index or by specifying an Order By clause in an SQL query." [http://www.digital-metaphors.com/download/pdf/RBuilder.pdf] (ReportBuilder, Developer's Guide Fourth Edition, p.294). So, I can't follow your advice...

Comment: That's exactly what I meant: you have to sort the data model. I added a clarification in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot but there's not "Data" tab (just Calc, Design and Preview) in the ReportBuilder I'm using, but there is a "Data" item in the "Report" menu which shows a list of DataPipelines available (obviously only one can be chosen).